# Treemap color-coding in D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

I am working with the [zoomable treemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezGe9.png) from D3. I plugged in my own data, but for some reason I don't get the same diversity of colors of the original visualization. Why?

[image]

As far as I can tell, this is where the color of the rects are defined:

```
  cell.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dx - 1; })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy - 1; })
      .attr("class", "rct")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.parent.name); });
```

with `color` defined here:

```
var w = 1280 - 80,
    h = 800 - 180,
    x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h]),
    color = d3.scale.category20c(),
    root,
    node;
```

I don't see anything that controls the number or choice of colors directly. What am  I missing?

Comment: Use `d3.scale.category10()` for greater contrast. See this [doc](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales), towards the end, for an explanation of the color categories.

Comment: Is it possible that you have only three different names?

Comment: Great point @LarsKotthoff...otherwise we should have seen more color variations (regardless of which in-built category was chosen).